# Preview popup guide does not stop to appear while typing flutter code in VS code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

While typing in Flutter dart code in VS code. the preview Popup box guide keeps on coming and remains displayed until full line of code is complete.  I don't know what feature this is called ( previewFlutterUiGuidesCustomTrackin  or suggest. preview or parameterHints.enabled ). The screenshot is shown..[image]

while typing code about color, I don't want the popup preview guide to get appear which really does not go away till whole of code is complete. This feature is really annoying as it completely hides the real code being typed.. I had gone through various solutions given in the website but nothing worked (the solution might be old which may not be compatible with the latest version of VS Code or Dart/flutter ).

### Please give some latest solutions for removing that preview pop up guide which appears during typing code..
My setting

VS Code: 1.71.0 ( latest till today 04/09/2022 )

Comment: Press `ctrl+space` key

Comment: I tried, but it did not work..

Comment: you like to disable all popup?

Comment: no.. I do want right side list of bottom commands suggestions but do not want left side each command preview guide which pops up along with command suggestions as shown in screenshot